# Can't cast to to unspecific nested type with generics

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have two classes with nested generics. Is there a way to get rid of the

**Type mismatch: cannot convert from `Msg<Value<String>>` to `Msg<Value<?>>`** error ?
In the last assignment

```
public class Value<V> {
    V   val;

    public Value(V val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + val;
    }
}

public class Msg<T> {

    T holder;

    public Msg( T holder) {
        this.holder = holder ;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "" + holder;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Msg<Value<String>>strMsg = new Msg(new Value<String>("abc"));
        // This is OK
        Msg<?>objMsg = strMsg;
        // Type mismatch: cannot convert from Msg<Value<String>> to Msg<Value<?>>   
        Msg<Value<?>>objMsg = strMsg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an explicit cast to see if you can at least tease out a better type error?

Comment: @Gian yes, same error message

Comment: you may want to consider type-inferring `static` factory methods instead of constructors; that way you don't have to parameterize `Msg` and `Value` every time you use `new`. Note that you forgot to parameterize `new Msg` in your original snippet, and used a raw type. See this question to see what type inferring `static` factory method can do for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542139/java-generics-syntax/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the following:

```
Msg<? extends Value<?>> someMsg = strMsg;
```

The problem is that the `?` in `Msg<Value<?>> objMsg` is *NOT* capable of capture conversion. It's not "a `Msg` of `Value` of *some* type. It's "a `Msg` of `Value` of *ANY* type".

This also explains why along with the declaration change, I've also renamed the variable to `someMsg`. The `Value` can't just be any `Object`. It must belong to *some* type (`String` in this example).

---

#### A more generic example

Let's consider a more generic example of a `List<List<?>>`. Analogously to the original scenario, a `List<List<?>>` can *NOT* capture-convert a `List<List<Integer>>`.

```
    List<List<Integer>> lolInt = null;

    List<List<?>> lolAnything = lolInt;         // DOES NOT COMPILE!!!
    // a list of "lists of anything"

    List<? extends List<?>> lolSomething = lolInt;   // compiles fine!
    // a list of "lists of something"
```

Here's another way to look at it:

- Java generics is type invariant
- There's a conversion from ***`Integer`*** to ***`Number`***, but a `List<`***`Integer`***`>` is not a `List<`***`Number`***`>`

  - Similarly, a ***`List<Integer>`*** can be capture-converted by a ***`List<?>`***, but a `List<`***`List<Integer>`***`>` is not a `List<`***`List<?>`***`>`
- Using bounded wildcard, a `List<? extends` ***`Number`***`>` can capture-convert a `List<`***`Integer`***`>`

  - Similarly, a `List<? extends` ***`List<?>`***`>` can capture-convert a `List<`***`List<Integer>`***`>`

The fact that some `?` can capture and others can't also explains the following snippet:

```
    List<List<?>> lolAnything = new ArrayList<List<?>>(); // compiles fine!

    List<?> listSomething = new ArrayList<?>(); // DOES NOT COMPILE!!!
        // cannot instantiate wildcard type with new!
```

#### Related questions

- [Multiple wildcards on a generic methods makes Java compiler (and me!) very confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546745/multiple-wildcards-on-a-generic-methods-makes-java-compiler-and-me-very-confus)

  - Very long and detailed exploration into this problem
- [Java Generic `List<List<? extends Number>>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746089/java-generic-listlist-extends-number)
- [Any simple way to explain why I cannot do `List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Dog>()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346763/any-simple-way-to-explain-why-i-cannot-do-listanimal-animals-new-arraylistdo)
- [What is the difference between `<E extends Number>` and `<Number>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770264/what-is-the-difference-between-e-extends-number-and-number)

#### See also

- [Java Generics Tutorial](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html)

  - [Generics and Subtyping](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html) | [Wildcards](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) | [More Fun with Wildcards](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/morefun.html)
- [Angelika Langer's Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

  - [What is a bounded wildcard?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#FAQ103)
  - [Which super-subtype relationships exist among instantiations of generic types?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ207)

Comment: +20 for all the links

Answer (score 4):

My answer is similar to another, but hopefully is more clear.

```
List<List<?>> is a list of (lists of anything).

List<List<String>> is a list of (lists of strings).
```

The latter cannot be converted to the former because doing so would allow you to add a List<Number> to your List<List<String>>, which would clearly be broken.

Note that the rules for this don't change if you replace List with some type that doesn't have .add.  Java would need declaration-site covariance and/or contravariance for that (like C#'s IEnumerable<out T> or Scala's List[+A]).  Java only has use-site covariance and contravariance (? extends X, ? super X).

Answer (score 3):

Although your generic type parameter contains a wildcard, it is not itself a wildcard. When assigning to a variable (`Msg<T>`) with a non-wildcard generic type `T`, the object being assigned must have exactly `T` as its generic type (including all generic type parameters of `T`, wildcard and non-wildcard). In your case `T` is `Value<String>`, which is not the same type as `Value<?>`.

What you can do, because `Value<String>` is assignable to `Value<?>`, is use the wildcard type:

```
Msg<? extends Value<?>> a = new Msg<Value<String>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer but i strongly recommend the reading of: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf to better understand generics.

Answer (score 0):

ILMTitan has a good solution, and if you don't want to make the class specific to Value you may as well use the base type instead of generics at this point because you'll be turning off a safety feature, but there is a way.  You might even be able to pass a parameter to make this method more generic, but the key is "@SuppressWarnings".

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Msg<Value<?>> convert()
{
    return (Msg<Value<?>>) this;
}
```

Comment: If `this` is a `Msg<Value<String>>`, this wouldn't compile. It's not an unchecked cast. It's a straightup _ILLEGAL_ cast. It's like trying to cast a `String` to an `Integer`.