# Java HashMap with ArrayList wildcards

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, hashmap, wildcard

I have a HashMap where the values are ArrayLists, and I'm trying to write a function to accept generic instances of these HashMaps

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> myMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
public static void foo(HashMap<?, ArrayList<?>> a) {}
public static void bar(HashMap<?, ? extends ArrayList<?>> a) {}

// Compilation Failure!
foo(myMap);

// This works, but why do I need ? extends ArrayList
bar(myMap)
```

The error message is

> The method `foo(HashMap<?,ArrayList<?>>)` in the type `Example` is not applicable
>   for the arguments (`HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>>`).

Why do I need to have a wildcard for the extends ArrayList?

I thought that by having `ArrayList<?>`(without the `? extends`), I could restrict the function to only HashMaps with ArrayList values.

I also know that the following generic method works:

```
public static <K,V> void printer(HashMap<K, ArrayList<V>> list) { }
```

Which behaves how I thought `ArrayList<?>` would work.  Can someone explain the subtleties here?

Comment: Either tell us the exact compiler error which is generated by `foo`, or give us an example of the code inside `foo` which causes the error. In fact, both pieces of information would help greatly

Comment: `The method foo(HashMap<?,ArrayList<?>>) in the type Example is not applicable for the arguments (HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>>)`

Comment: The error I get is the same as Michael Brewer

Answer (score 6):

The wildcard syntax was deliberately designed to (mis)lead people to believe it matches any type. This works for simple cases

```
List<?> <= List<String> // OK, right is subtype of left
```

But remember, it only works on the 1st level, not deeper

```
List<List<?> <= List<List<String>>  // FAIL
```

This is fine

```
List<? extends List<?>> <= List<List<String>>
```

because of the new 1st level `?`. 
If `S` is subtype of `T`, `G<S>` is subtype of `G<? extends T>`. Apply that in case of`S=List<String>`, `T=List<?>`.

Comment: Do you have any citations for this? I did verify this is the case but I'm just curious where it's documented.

Comment: ok. also found a similar answer with lots of references http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575681/cant-cast-to-to-unspecific-nested-type-with-generics/3575895#3575895

Comment: Bala R: First hit on Google hold a good tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: in JLS3, #4.10.2 subtyping rules. you'll see only the 1st level wildcard is addressed. Also in #5.1.10 "Capture conversion is not applied recursively."

Answer (score 1):

1. The type `HashMap<?, ArrayList<?>>` means about *a map which maps keys of some unknown (fixed) type to lists, each of which has elements of some unknown fixed type*.
2. A concrete instantiation of such a map would be, for example:

   ```
   new HashMap<String, ArrayList<?>>();
   ```

   This is a map in which **we can add arbitrary ArrayLists** as values, and for values (lists) we get out of them we don't know anything about the parameter type.
3. The type `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>` means *a map from strings to lists of integer*. This is a map in which we can only add ArrayLists of Integers as values, **not arbitrary ArraysLists**. Thus, it cannot be a subtype of the type 2 (since it allows less than it).

   (Type 1 is a supertype of 2, which also lets the key type unknown.)
4. The type `HashMap<String, ? extends ArrayList<?>>` means *a map from strings to some unknown type, which is only known to be a subtype of `ArrayList<?>`*. In such a map we can't insert anything (as value), but all values we get out of it are guaranteed to be of type `ArrayList<?>`, i.e. a arraylist of something unknown (which may be another something for each list). We can insert new String keys, but only with a `null` value.

   Both type 2 and type 3 are subtypes of type 4 (since both `ArrayList<?>` and `ArrayList<Integer>`  fulfill the `extends ArrayList<?>` condition), but not of each other.
5. `HashMap<?, ? extends ArrayList<?>>` is like 4, but we don't know the key type, either. This means we can't really do anything with the map, apart from iterating it (or looking up values for keys - `get()` takes an `Object` argument, not `K`) and removing stuff. For the values we retrieve, we only can iterate and remove stuff, not insert or even reorder anything.  (I.e. type 4 is a subtype of type 5.)
6. The method argument type `HashMap<K, ArrayList<V>>` with type variables `<K, V>` means *a map from some type K to lists of some type V, where K and V are decided by the caller of the method*. The type 3 obviously fits this (with `<String, Integer>`), thus you are allowed to call this method. You can't really put new keys into the map, since your method does not know what `K` is, but you could map existing keys to new values. You can use `new ArrayList<V>()` (and put these elements into the map as values), but you can only put existing `V` objects from your existing lists into these lists. Still a lot more possible than with type 5.

---

Just a side note: You should have used the more general types `Map<K,V>` and `List<E>` instead of `HashMap<K,V>` and `ArrayList<E>` for your methods, since most certainly the method will work on any type of map/list and does not care about the specific implementation. You also would use

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> myMap = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
```

to declare and initialize your variable. (You can still put `ArrayList<Integer>` objects as values.)

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. `HashMap<K, V>` is not a subtype of `HashMap<K, W>` even if `V` is a subtype of `W`. (You know this already, right?) Here, `V` is `ArrayList<Integer>`, and `W` is `ArrayList<?>`. (What matters is that they are different.) Yes, `ArrayList<Integer>` is a subtype of `ArrayList<?>`, but that's what we covered earlier, i.e. it's irrelevant. However, `HashMap<K, V>` *is* a subtype of `HashMap<K, ? extends W>`, because of the wildcard.