# Compilation failure calling method with nested wildcard

Tags: java, generics

I am having an issue with generics in java, specifically with wildcards. I have a `Map` (`outerMap`), whose values are another `Map` (`innerMap`) elements, whose values are `List` elements.

See the following java class, which I have created to demonstrate this behaviour. Import statements are not included. Ignore the use of streams inside the methods, that is irrelevant:

```
public class SSCCE {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Setup
    List<Double> doubles = Arrays.asList(1.0,2.0,3.0);
    Map<Integer, List<Double>> innerMap = new HashMap<>();
    innerMap.put(1, doubles);
    Map<String, Map<Integer, List<Double>>> outerMap = new HashMap<>();
    outerMap.put("hello", innerMap);

    // Test    
    // This method call works fine. 
    Stream<Integer> streamFromInner = getStreamOfMappingToN(innerMap);

    // This method call does not work - causes below compilation error.
    Stream<Integer> stream = getStreamOfMergedDistinctMappingToN(outerMap);
  }

  private static <T, U> Stream<T> getStreamOfMappingToN(Map<T, ? extends Collection<U>> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream().map(q -> q.getKey());
  }

  private static <T, U> Stream<T> getStreamOfMergedDistinctMappingToN(Map<String, Map<T, ? extends Collection<U>>> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream().flatMap(
            p -> getStreamOfMappingToN(p.getValue())
    ).distinct();
  }
}
```

I am seeing the following compilation error, on the second method call:

```
method getStreamOfMergedDistinctMappingToN in class SSCCE cannot be applied to given types;
  required: Map<String,Map<T,? extends Collection<U>>>
  found: Map<String,Map<Integer,List<Double>>>
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) T,U
    (argument mismatch; Map<String,Map<Integer,List<Double>>> cannot be converted to Map<String,Map<T,? extends Collection<U>>>)
  where T,U are type-variables:
    T extends Object declared in method <T,U>getStreamOfMergedDistinctMappingToN(Map<String,Map<T,? extends Collection<U>>>)
    U extends Object declared in method <T,U>getStreamOfMergedDistinctMappingToN(Map<String,Map<T,? extends Collection<U>>>)
```

Can anybody suggest why this happening with the second method call, and not with the first? Both method signatures contain `Map<T, ? extends Collection<U>>`, but only the second fails to match against the call. If I replace the problematic `? extends Collection<U>` with `List<U>`, it works fine because I am actually passing it a `List`, but that seems lazy and does not explain why I am seeing this error.

I have done a bit of reading around on this, some people have had similar problems and have had their problems explained - many remark that the level of the wildcard matters -  but without an understanding of what is going on here it is hard for me to relate other solutions to this problem. It is still quite confusing. Through reading I have found that if I replace `Map<T, ? extends Collection<U>>` with `? extends Map<T, ? extends Collection<U>>` in the second method declaration, it compiles fine, but I don't understand why, and then why the first method signature would work.

I would appreciate your feedback on this.

Comment: A more practical problem with this code (even when you make it compile) is that it is very difficult to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @biziclop Sure, this isn't my actual code, it just exhibits the problem. I am using streams for mapping from `Entry` to `T` based on what is in the `Collection`, but I left a lot of that out as I didn't think it was relevant to the problem. Also the same goes for T and U, they could be anything.

Comment: http://bayou.io/draft/Capturing_Wildcards.html#Nested_Wildcards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your methods to the following:

```
private static <T, U extends Collection<?>> Stream<T> getStreamOfMappingToN(Map<T, U> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream().map(q -> q.getKey());
}

private static <T, U extends Collection<?>> Stream<T> getStreamOfMergedDistinctMappingToN(Map<String, Map<T, U>> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
            .flatMap(p -> getStreamOfMappingToN(p.getValue())).distinct();
}
```

What changed is that instead of declaring the input type as `? extends Collection<U>`, the method is accepting `Map<T, U>` but `U` is constrained to `U extends Collection<?>`.

This change represents what you really want to do: you are giving a `Map` as input. This map has two types `T` and `U`. `T` can be whatever type we give but `U` really needs to be a `Collection` of something, i.e. `U` must `extends Collection<?>`.

---

To find out why your example doesn't compile, please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6603284/1743880) (or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3575895/1743880)): wildcards only works on the 1st level, not deeper. As you found out, you need to add `? extends Map<...>` to counter the fact that the wildcard was not applied recursively.

Still, I would recommend you use the first solution as I feel it gives cleaner code and the proper intent, instead of messing around with wildcards.