# How to properly cast nested generic types in Java

Tags: java, generics, casting

In Java I can cast:

```
List<?> j = null;
List<Integer> j2 = (List<Integer>)j;
```

So why does the following fail?

```
List<List<?>> i = null;
List<List<Integer>> i2 = (List<List<Integer>>)i;
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: This explains it so so well : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546745/multiple-wildcards-on-a-generic-methods-makes-java-compiler-and-me-very-confu

Comment: Both casts are a pretty bad idea, it's just that the first one is dubious (not provably correct), the latter one is flat out wrong.

Comment: What you *can* cast, though, is `List<?>` into `List<List<Integer>>`---because `?` can stand for anything, including `List<Integer>`.

Answer (score 6):

In your 1<sup>st</sup> snippet:

```
List<?> j = null;
List<Integer> j2 = (List<Integer>)j;
```

The compiler won't give you error, because `List<?>` is a super type of `List<Integer>`, because the family of types denoted by the wildcard `"?"` is a superset of `Integer`. So you can perform the cast from `List<?>` to `List<Integer>` (A downcast, you can say), but the compiler will show you an *Unchecked Warning*, to save you against a cast from say - `List<Date>` to `List<Integer>`. The warning is shown, because the cast would otherwise succeed at runtime, due to type erasure.

---

In the 2<sup>nd</sup> case:

```
List<List<?>> i = null;
List<List<Integer>> i2 = (List<List<Integer>>)i;
```

Here you are casting from `List<List<?>>` (referred to by *FIRST* from hereon) to `List<List<Integer>>`(referred to by *SECOND* from hereon).

Since, *FIRST* is not a super type of *SECOND*, clearly because the family of types denoted by `List<?>` (it can be `List<Long>`, `List<Date>`, `List<String>` or anything) is not a super set of `List<Integer>`. Hence a *Compiler Error*.

**Suggested Reading:**

- [Angelika Langer - Generics FAQs](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ207)
- [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Comment: *"[...] the family of types denoted by `List<?>` [...] is not a super set of `List<Integer>`.* It actually is! Any object of type `List<Integer>` matches the more general type `List<?>`.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
List<? extends List<?>> i = null;

List<List<Integer>> i2 = (List<List<Integer>>)i;
```

Source (this source will reference to other great sources):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3575895/2498729

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you need to do a wildcard cast to cast it to what you want.

```
List<?> j = null;
List<Integer> j2 = (List<Integer>)j;

List<List<?>> i = null;
List<List<Integer>> i2 = (List<List<Integer>>) (List<?>) i;
```

That compiles fine. You just needed to do an additional cast just to add a little buffer.

See here: http://ideone.com/xh88lX

If you want to know why, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575681/cant-cast-to-to-unspecific-nested-type-with-generics)

Basically, here's the relevant info
Here's another way to look at it:

- Java generics is type invariant
- There's a conversion from Integer to Number, but a `List<Integer>` is not a `List<Number>`
- Similarly, a `List<Integer>` can be capture-converted by a `List<?>`, but a `List<List<Integer>>` is not a `List<List<?>>`
- Using bounded wildcard, a `List<? extends Number>` can capture-convert a `List<Integer>`
- Similarly, a `List<? extends List<?>>` can capture-convert a `List<List<Integer>>`

Comment: I just looked it up a little more, and found another stackoverflow post that explains why, check my edit.

Comment: I didn't see that till I posted, I'll still leave it up here since it provides another solution

Comment: The only answer that actually answers the question of *how* to do it has the least upvotes :/