# Issue with interface as Map key & value

Tags: java

In a library project, I have :

```
public interface InterfaceA {
}

public interface InterfaceB {
}

public void myMethod(Map<? extends InterfaceA, List<? extends InterfaceB>> map) {
//do something
}
```

Then I have another project (having this library as a dependency) that contains two object implementing these interfaces :

```
public class ObjectA implements InterfaceA {
}

public class ObjectB implements InterfaceB {
}
```

When I try to call the library method `myMethod` like this :

```
HashMap<ObjectA, List<ObjectB>> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
//populate hashmap
myMethod(hashMap);
```

I get a compilation warning saying there is an argument mismatch.

What am I missing here ? Does it have something to do with the map ?

EDIT : 
The exact error (it's not a warning actually) is :

```
incompatible types: HashMap<ObjectA,List<ObjectB>> cannot be     converted to Map<? extends InterfaceA,List<? extends InterfaceB>>
```

Comment: Are you missing a > in your method declaration?

Comment: I fixed the post.

Comment: is the original code correct?

Comment: Yes, the error is an argument mismatch. It's just that I did not copy/paste the code, and made a mistake.

Comment: Paste, don't paraphrase, the warning.

Comment: Is there any chance you have another type declared somewhere called `InterfaceA`, `InterfaceB`, `ObjectA`, `ObjectB`, `List` or `Map` that is not the type you are expecting?

Comment: @khelwood No, it's reproducible (in Eclipse)

Comment: @khelwood No. I've checked imports on both files and they both import `java.util.List` and `java.util.Map`.

Comment: possible answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575681/cant-cast-to-to-unspecific-nested-type-with-generics/3575895#3575895

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics are invariant.

If your method declares:

```
Map<? extends InterfaceA, List<? extends InterfaceB>>
```

Then the second type parameter has to be **exactly** `List<? extends InterfaceB>`.

You can fix it by using:

```
Map<? extends InterfaceA, ? extends List<? extends InterfaceB>>
```

Instead.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick, even if I don't clearly understand the syntax here. I clearly have to read a bit more about generics.

Answer (score 1):

You either modify your Hashmap creation for this:

```
Map<? extends InterfaceA, List<? extends InterfaceB>> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
```

or modify your method definition for this:

```
public <A extends InterfaceA, B extends InterfaceB> void myMethod(Map<A, List<B>> map) {
    //do something
  }
```

Comment: What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Declare your map as

```
HashMap<ObjectA, List<? extends InterfaceB>> hashMap = new HashMap<ObjectA, List<? extends InterfaceB>>();
```